# certbot does not recognize the added VirtualHost

Tags: linux, arch-linux, apache-httpd, configuration, apache-virtualhost

I'm trying to use certbot to get a certificate for my http server running nextcloud (archarm on a raspi). When I run: `$ sudo certbot --apache`, I get:

```
$ sudo certbot --apache      
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
No names were found in your configuration files. Please enter in your domain
name(s) (comma and/or space separated)  (Enter 'c' to cancel):
```

I then enter my domain: `example.duckdns.org` upon which I get:

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for example.duckdns.org
Cleaning up challenges
Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.
```

While I do have `example_duckdns.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf/extra` which looks like:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/nextcloud>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/nextcloud"
    ServerName example.duckdns.org
    ServerAlias example.duckdns.org
    ServerAdmin example@mymail.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log_example_duckdns_org"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log_example_duckdns_org" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And I get:

```
$ apachectl configtest        
Syntax OK
```

What do I have wrong?

Using: `Apache/2.4.43`

Comment: @telcoM yep, you're right, I did not include my VirtualHost file n the Apache conf. Once I did this, the domain was recognized correctly! You can move this comment into an aswer and I'll accept gladly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, your `/etc/httpd/conf/extra` looks correct, but does your main Apache configuration file (or any file included by it) have anything like `Include /etc/httpd/conf/extra` or `IncludeOptional /etc/httpd/conf/*` in it anywhere?